# How prove $\frac{a^2}{a+2b^2}+\frac{b^2}{b+2c^2}+\frac{c^2}{c+2a^2}\ge 1$

Tags: inequality

> let $a,b,c$ be postive real numbers ,and such $$ab+bc+ac=3$$
>   show that
>   $$\dfrac{a^2}{a+2b^2}+\dfrac{b^2}{b+2c^2}+\dfrac{c^2}{c+2a^2}\ge 1$$

This problem is from Secrets In Inequalities volume 1  page 30,example 1.24. the comment.the  author this case is a bit more diffcult,But this author can't post solution.Thank you

[image]

Comment: If $a=b=c=1$ then certainly $ab+bc+ac=3$ but it doesn't work for the inequality. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I think the "second case is a bit more difficult" regarded the $\sqrt a + \sqrt b + \sqrt c $ inequality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By AM-GM (with all sums being cyclic), 
$$\sum \frac{a^2}{a+2b^2} = \sum a - \sum \frac{2ab^2}{a+2b^2}\ge \sum a - \sum \frac{2ab^2}{3\sqrt[3]{ab^4}}= \sum a - \frac23\sum (ab)^{2/3}$$

By Power Mean Inequality,  $$1 = \frac{ab+bc+ca}3 \ge \sqrt[\frac23]{\frac{\sum (ab)^{2/3}}3} \implies \sum (ab)^{2/3} \le 3$$

It remains to show that $\sum a \ge 3$ which follows from the well known
$$\left(\sum a\right)^2 \ge 3\sum ab = 9$$

Comment: Shouldn't the $\frac{3}{2}$ in the root be a $\frac{2}{3}$?

Comment: i'm not very knowledgeable of this topic, so I just wanted to make sure before making any accusations :)

Comment: @MichaelT That's perfectly OK, and in fact thanks - my typo.

Comment: how can you write $1 = \frac{ab+bc+ca}3 \ge \sqrt[\frac23]{\frac{\sum (ab)^{2/3}}3}$???

Comment: i get by am-gm $ab+bc+ca /3$ > abc^ (2/3)..!

Comment: @User88463 Read up on Power Means Inequality: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Generalized_mean_inequality.   The statement used above follows directly from $1> \frac23$.

Comment: got it, thanks..

Comment: @Macavity can you pls give some hint on case 2 i.e when $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}=3$ ....

Comment: i till now proved that $a+b+c$ has to be greater then or equal 3...but i am not able to show that in this case also $(a b)^{2 / 3}+(b c)^{2 / 3}+(c a)^{2 / 3} \leq 3$...any hint on which inequality should we use here ?

Comment: I suggest you post it as a separate problem, rather than adding this on to comments in a post from 5-6 years ago.

Comment: ok,posted you can check..